# showing app image instead of user image in invitation link

Tags: facebook

i made an applicaion on facebook.I have also option invite friend.It works fine but in friends invite link request, there come my picture.But i need that app picture instead of mine.
Is there any way to show app image instead of those who send invitation ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. That's how it was designed.